# Angular highlight directive to highlight the div on click

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out how to highlight the div on mouse click in a way that only one item should be highlighted. If i do (onmouseup) ( it does not recognize onmouseclick or onmouseClick ) all items are being highlighted. Following is the directive code. **[Here is the Plnkr Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/mIzbpW?p=preview)**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef}  from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector:'[highlight]',
  host: {
    '(mouseup)': 'onMouseUp()',
  }

//  host: {
//    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter()',
//    '(mouseleave)': 'onMouseLeave()',
//  }
})
export class Highlight{
  private el:ElementRef;
  constructor(el:ElementRef){
    this.el = el;
  }


  onMouseEnter(){
    console.log(this.el);
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#D1D301';
  }
  onMouseLeave(){
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }

  onMouseUp(){
    console.log(this.el);
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#D1D301';
  }
}
```

Comment: When the user clicks at a square, you want all others to get back to white, is that it?

Comment: This will be difficult to do the way you have it structured.  Your directive would need to traverse the DOM and make assumptions about the DOM structure (not good).  Instead of one directive for the entire list, a likely better design would be to add the directive to each item, and have it emit an event (use an Output property) when the mouse is clicked.  The parent   component would then iterate through its list and call a public method on the directive to unhighlight each item.  Then it would call a public method on the directive to highlight the one.  Similar to a tabs implementation.

Comment: Look into ng-class

Comment: Please change the plnkr and see if you can make it work. Thanks

Comment: [I edited your plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vk89Es?p=preview), I changed the event to click "You could still use mouseup", and changed your styles to `HostBinding`. Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thanks Abdulrahman but this is not what i was looking for. Thierry Templier has solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reference the list of elements using the `@ViewChildren` directive and unselect the current select element based on this. This list must be provided as input of each element.

Here is a sample:

```
@Directive({
  selector:'[highlight]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'select()',
  }
})
export class Highlight{
  private el:ElementRef;

  constructor(el:ElementRef){
    this.el = el;
  }

  @Input()
  elements;

  select(){
    this.elements.forEach(elt => {
      elt.unselect();
    });

    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#D1D301';
  }

  unselect() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
}
```

And the way to use this directive:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'itemdisplay',
  directives:[Highlight]
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
      <div style="display:inline-block; height:80px; width: 70px; border:1px solid black;" highlight [elements]="elements">
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ItemDisplay{
  @ViewChildren(Highlight)
  elements:Highlight[];

  public items = [
    {id:1, name:"Item1"}
    {id:2, name:"Item2"}
    {id:3, name:"Item3"}
    {id:4, name:"Item4"}
    {id:5, name:"Item5"}    
  ];
}
```

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LnOMPv?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how ViewChildren works, but this is exactly i was looking for. I will look into ViewChildren documentation. Is there any way to improve your solution. Ideally i would just like to specify "highlight" as my attribute and thats it. Using [elements]="elements" with highlight attribute is kind of something extra.. Just a thought.